# assign select statement as variable in nested query

Tags: sqlite, variables

```
 String query1 = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name LIKE 'a_'";
 String query2 = "SELECT * FROM ( '" + query1 + "' ) WHERE age = '55'";
```

i have  tried to put query1 as a variable for the nested select query, the error shown in java is this...
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database.
How to assign query1 as variable?

Comment: It does not look like the **result** of the first query is ending up in the string variable `query1`. You probably need to first execute that query and then use the (hopefully single-word) result in the concatenation you seem to attempt in the second query.

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. Seeing how you use those string variables will probably help with answering your question.

Comment: `query2` ends up being `SELECT * FROM ( 'SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name LIKE 'a_'' ) WHERE age = '55'` doesn't it? The `'a_''` looks fishy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code `query2` ends up being

```
SELECT * FROM ( 'SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name LIKE 'a_'' ) WHERE age = '55'
```

If you change

```
String query2 = "SELECT * FROM ( '" + query1 + "' ) WHERE age = '55'";
```

to

```
String query2 = "SELECT * FROM ( " + query1 + " ) WHERE age = '55'";
```

(note the deleted `'`) it ends up:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name LIKE 'a_' ) WHERE age = '55'
```

which should be correct SQLite syntax.

I suspect that error on missing database is coming from a "confused" SQLite and could be solved by fixing the syntax. Otherwise please provide the result of this change, preferrably in the shape of a MCVE.

I do not get the purpose of that query by the way, it seems somewhat roundabout...